# Hellinger distance between Gaussians - multivariate and univariate forms

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

On pages 46 and 51 of the book Statistical Inference based on divergence measures By Leandro Pardo Llorente there is a derivation for the Hellinger distance between two multivariate Gaussian distributions (the sample pages can be viewed on google [books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ziDGGIkhqlMC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=statistical+inference+and+divergence+measures+chapter+1&source=bl&ots=m-giDrMnA0&sig=oJ0DVrUIy_Ff3IA9GYv_TZP-eIo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TOuwUMjAMeaD4ATL6YDYCQ&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=statistical%20inference%20and%20divergence%20measures%20chapter%201&f=false)). If  vectors of length 1 are used with this form and both distributions assumed to have zero means, then the exponential portion of the hellinger distance goes to unity. However this does not give the same result as the Hellinger distance between two univariate [Gaussians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) under the same assumptions. Shouldn't these two forms be consistent under these assumptions?

[image: Univariate form]

[image: Multivariate form]

(with $u=(\mu_1-\mu_2)$)

Comment: They look the same, setting $\Sigma_{i}=\sigma_{i}^2$ for $i=1,2$...

Comment: Whoops - yes your correct. Thanks.